# Codename One on Android a.a$b.iterator() on a null object reference (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, codenameone

I'm not sure exactly where the error is as I can't reproduce it in the simulator? it also works fine on IOS

If I send the code to Android I get the error.

```
An internal application error occurred:
java.util.Iterator
a.a$b.iterator() on a null object reference
```

The method is from `RESTfulWebServiceClient`

```
public void find(Query query, SuccessCallback<RowSet> callback)
```

The error occurs if I try to use the callback

```
for (Map m : callback) {
...
}
```

Edit...

Check my answer, turns out it was SQLite when using * in the select statement.

Comment: sounds like callback is null

Comment: I'm sure it is, but only when on an Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem to be with Android and SQLite. I believe this may only affect Android 4.

I was using a select statement on the SQLite database to populate the id of the restful find method. However, when using the select statement I used "select * from table" and then the column number as the output variable. It turns out, on Android, if you use * the output of the columns is not the order that they are created.

So when I selected * and then used column 4 on the simulator and ISO it worked fine, but when I used it on Android the output for column 4 was column 3.

I have fixed this by explicitly selecting the columns I need. it means select statements are longer but at least they work.

Comment: If you pass `*` then returned column may be in any order so any assumption about that is simply incorrect. You should either specify columns in your query (so you will get it in that order) or use Cursor's methods like `getColumnIndex()` to get correct index.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the former

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [rowset can be null](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-generic-webservice-client/blob/master/GenericWebserviceClient/src/com/codename1/ws/RESTfulWebServiceClient.java#L205-L218) regardless on platform. Not sure why this happens to you only on Android, I guess some other logic triggered that state.

Comment: Thanks Shai,  I have found the answer and it doesn't have anything to with the rest class directly...